# how to Show data on a web browser control?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wants to show simple string in web browser.And as per bellow code when i am run application it will not show any string and not give error.

so how can i show string or html cantent in web broser controll.

XMl Code is

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" Height="595" Foreground="Black" />
        </Grid>
```

My C# cod is:

```
 public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Loaded += WebBrowser_OnLoaded;
        }

        private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=480, user-scalable=yes' /></head><body><h2>Welcome to F5debug!</h2><p>To get more updates visit www.f5Debug.net</p></body></html>
            webBrowser1.NavigateToString("hello");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Page2() { 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.NavigateToString("hello"); 
}
}
```

Is this ok?